# raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model) ValueError: Related model 'MDShop.user' cannot be resolved

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can you help me please?I want to put additional information on the User but it does not work

```
 File "C:\django 5\Новая папка (14)\Musa\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\django 5\Новая папка (14)\Musa\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 322, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 159, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 212, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1004, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1001, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 897, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 644, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 632, in related_fields
    return self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 936, in resolve_related_fields
    related_fields = super().resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 615, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'MDShop.user' cannot be resolved
```

settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'MDShop.User'
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'MDShop',
    'mptt',
    'corsheaders',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'knox',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    ]
```

Hello!Can you help me please?I want to put additional information on the User but it does not workHello!Can you help me please?I want to put additional information on the User but it does not workHello!Can you help me please?I want to put additional information on the User but it does not work

Comment: `MDShop.User` is MDshop your app name in which you have defined the User model?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes

Comment: Have you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat all done

Comment: What does that mean? Does it work now?

Comment: @AsylkhanMustafa, can you add your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your question.

Comment: @NKSM ...........

Comment: @AsylkhanMustafa run migrations again. So `manage.py makemigrations MDShop` and
`manage.py migrate MDShop`.